# How do I order a has_many through association in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

Given the following AR models, I would like to sort users alphabetically by last name when given a handle to a task:

```
#user
has_many :assignments
has_many :tasks, :through => :assignments    

#assignment
belongs_to :task
belongs_to :user

#task
has_many :assignments
has_many :users, :through => :assignments
```

I would like to get a task then navigation to its assigned users, *and sort the user list alphabetically*.

I keep thinking that I should be able to add the `:order` clause to `has_many :users, :through => :assignments` like this:

```
#task.rb
has_many :assignments
has_many :users, :through => :assignments, :order => 'last_name, first_name'
```

however this does not work.

How can I sort users by `last_name` when given a task?

Answer (score 72):

Since condition arguments are deprecated in Rails 4, one should use scope blocks:

```
has_many :users, -> { order 'users.last_name, users.first_name' }, :through => :assignments
```

Comment: It looks like there is currently a bug in Rails 4 with this https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17904 "In Rails 4.0, the order clause was ignored. In Rails 4.1, invalid SQL is generated."

Comment: It doesn't even give me that, just completely ignores the order clause with no message.

Answer (score 37):

Rails 3.x version:

```
has_many :users, :through => :assignments, :order => 'users.last_name, users.first_name'
```

UPDATE: This only works in Rails 3.x (maybe before that too). For 4+, see other answers.

Comment: Works fine for me as well.  Clean solution that doesn't affect other functions of the sorted model as the first answer does.

Comment: not working, it says :order is not a key. Below answer of Denial IS working.

Answer (score 12):

The `M.G.Palmer's` approach works well, however table name is involved. There is a better way to do it:

```
has_many :users, :through => :assignments, :order => [ :last_name, :first_name ]
```

Comment: but what if the order is determined by the join table? e.g. assignments ... 
but without defining a default scope on assignments..

Answer (score 7):

This works for me (Rails 4.2)

Applying an ordering on the through map is not preserved, aka this is not enough to have the genres ordered:

```
has_many    :disk_genre_maps,
            -> {order('disk_genre_map.sort_order')},
            :inverse_of => :disk,
            :dependent  => :destroy,
            :autosave   => true


has_many    :genres,    # not sorted like disk_genre_maps
            :through    => :disk_genre_maps,
            :source     => :genre,
            :autosave   => true
```

So I overwrite this per instance:

```
def genres  # redefine genres per instance so that the ordering is preserved
    self.disk_genre_maps.map{|dgm|dgm.genre}
end
```

To make that work for assignments, this should be something like this (untested)

```
def genres= some_genres
    self.disk_genre_maps = some_genres.map.with_index do |genre, index|
        DiskGenreMap.new(disk:self, genre:genre, sort_order:index)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I am using Rails (5.0.0.1) and could make the sort with this syntax in my model Group that has many users through group_users:

```
# Associations.
has_many :group_users
has_many :users, -> { order(:name) }, through: :group_users
```

Adjust the code to your need that will work.

Answer (score 6):

Would this work for you?

```
# User.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 default_scope :order => 'last_name ASC'
 ...
end
```

You can define other named scopes for when sorting needs to be different.

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/18/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-scoping

Comment: Sorry to bump an old question, but this might be relevant to future readers: Some plugins (acts_as_list for example) don't work properly with default_scope.

Comment: Also bumping this as I had a similar issue, but needed to sort on a field IN the :through table — the awesome thing is that default_scope works in the :through table as well, and records retrieved via that relationship will respect the order.

Comment: Having `default_scope` is a very bad practice. There are many aricles written on this topic, for example: https://piechowski.io/post/why-is-default-scope-bad-rails/

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a new 'sort_order' column on the assignment table, and add a default scope like

```
default_scope { order('sort_order desc')}
```

to your assignments model.

Answer (score 1):

has_many :users, -> { order(:last_name, :first_name) }, :through => :assignments, source: 'user'