# handling order with has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models: project and task (for example) with a join model: project_task enabling a has_many through relationship so that tasks may be shared across projects.

I have specified position as an attribute of the project_task model. Now I want to be able to access tasks by their position in the project_tasks table via a given project.

i.e. project.tasks (ordered by the position listed for each task in the project_tasks table).

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I order a has_many through association in Ruby on Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205618/how-do-i-order-a-has-many-through-association-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think something like that can help you:

```
has_many :project_tasks
has_many :tasks, :through => :project_tasks, :order => 'project_tasks.position'
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry,  that's exactly it

Answer (score 2):

```
class Task < AR::Base
   belongs_to :project
   has_one :project_tasks,:through=>:project_tasks
end

class Project < AR::Base 
  has_many :project_tasks
  has_many :tasks ,:through=>:project_tasks,:order => 'project_tasks.position'
end

class ProjectTask < AR::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me in Rails 5.x :

```
has_many :project_tasks
has_many :tasks, -> { order('project_tasks.position') }, through: :project_tasks
```