# Rails order a has_many relation using a through table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have a User and a Campaign model in my rails app. A campaign `has_many` users and a user `has_one` campaign.

I want to order the users in the campaign by the date that they were added to it.

To do that, I created a through table called CampaignUser. I thought that I'd be able to order by the `created_at` column in that table, but I couldn't see an easy way to do it. See the classes below:

```
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :campaign_users
  has_many :users, through: :campaign_users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :campaign, through: :campaign_users, dependent: :destroy
end

class CampaignUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Ideally, I'd like to write a line like this in my Campaign class:

```
has_many :users, through: campaign_users, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
```

Where `created_at` refers to `campaign_users` and not to `users`. Is there a way to do that?

I could just write a method on Campaign myself to order the users manually, but then I'd have to make sure I call that method everywhere instead. It seems like there should be an easier way.

**Edit:**

Adding a scope to the user, [as suggested in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205618/how-do-i-order-a-has-many-through-association-in-ruby-on-rails) is more problematic in this case. I'm looking to order users by a property of the through table, not a property of the user itself. Is there a way to write the following line, replacing `email` with `campaign_users.created_at`, or something similar?

```
has_many :users, -> { order(email: :desc) }, :through => :campaign_users
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I order a has\_many through association in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205618/how-do-i-order-a-has-many-through-association-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: @mrzasa This case is slightly different as I'm trying to order based on the through table and not the user itself. See my edit for details.

Comment: I'd advise to remove `through` and implement it as two separate `has_many :campaign_users` associations in both classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT : Thanks to @AdColvin I changed the code block to make it work ;)

Have you tried something like

```
has_many :users, -> { order('campaign_users.created_at DESC') }, through: campaign_users
```

You can do that because ActiveRecord will generate a JOIN in the resulting SQL, then you can order on any table that is joined.

Also, the `campaign_users` in the order statement should be the name of the table, not the name of the model or the relation

Comment: This worked for me, with a slight modification. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is as @kevcha has already pointed out calling order with a string of the column you want.

But instead of adding the order clause directly to the association you may want to use a [association extension](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :campaign_users
  has_many :users, through: :campaign_users do
    def order_by_join_date
      order('campaign_users.created_at DESC')
    end
  end
end
```

This lets you call `campaign.users.order_by_join_date` to explicitly get the records in a specific order. It avoids some of the same [pitfalls that surround default scope](https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/).

Answer (score 0):

@kevcha When I tried your answer exactly as you suggested, I got the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting => ...mpaign_users.created_at
>   ASC') }

But, when I add the scope just after `has_many :users`, it works fine:

```
has_many :users, -> { order('campaign_users.created_at DESC') }, through: :campaign_users
```

Also worth noting is that `created_at` seems to be identical for objects created from a fixture. I wasn't aware of that. I had to explicitly set created_at in my fixtures for my tests around this to pass.